# Webpack compiled javascript not working on android in development mode

Tags: javascript, webpack

When I compile my javascript with **Webpack** in **development** mode, it doesn't work on **Android** devices, while it works fine everywhere else. When I compile it in **production** mode it works on **Android** as well. Can anybody tell why this is? It would make more sense if something breaks because of the minification, but it seems so strange to me that the beautified code doesn't work while the minified code works.

update: By "it doesn't work", I mean that not a single line of code is run. Not a single "console.log()", "alert()", or anything else. I don't receive any errors since it's working fine everywhere but on Android. I am using testingbot.com to test on android, so I don't have a debugging console, which makes me very blind. I also tried to reduce all code and dependencies down to jquery only, but even in this case, nothing is working on android, when the code is compiled in development mode.

My config file:

```
module.exports = {
   entry: entry,
   output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname+'/public/dist', 'js'),
    filename: '[name]-min.js'
  },
  mode:'production',
  optimization:{
    minimizer:minimizer
  },
  plugins: plugins,
  module:{
    rules: rules
  },
}
```

The minimizer object:

```
module.exports = [
  new TerserPlugin(),
  new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({})
]
```

The Plugins:

```
module.exports = [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery",
    jquery: "jquery",
    "window.jQuery": "jquery",
    "window.$": "jquery",
    swal: "sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.js"
  }),
  new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: "../css/[name].css",
    chunkFilename: "[id].css"
  }),
  new WriteToFilePlugin({
    filename: path.resolve(__dirname + '/../../src', 'assetVersion.js'),
    data: 'module.exports = ' + Number(assetVersion + 1)
  }),
  new HardSourceWebpackPlugin(),
]
```

The Rules:

```
module.exports = [{
    test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
    use: [
      { loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader },
      { loader: 'css-loader' },
      {
        loader: 'postcss-loader', // Run postcss actions
        options: {
          plugins: function() { // postcss plugins, can be exported to postcss.config.js
            return [
              require('autoprefixer')
            ];
          }
        }
      },
      { loader: 'sass-loader' },
    ],
  },
  {
    test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    use: [{
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
        name: '[name].[ext]',
        outputPath: '../../fonts/',
        publicPath: '/fonts'
      }
    }]
  },
  {
    test: /\.m?js$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
    use: {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
        plugins: ['transform-es2015-arrow-functions']
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? You should include a description of what is not working, along with the full text of any relevant errors messages you are seeing.

Comment: I am sorry, by "it doesn't work" I mean that no javascript is run. Not a single "console.log" is run. Even if I reduce all dependencies to jQuery only. I don't receive any error messages, since I am testing on an android device via testingbot.com and I don't have the possibility to open a debugging console ...